# Android - display BLE data

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to receive a 4-byte characteristic value over BLE, parse the data into 4 different variables, and then display them using textView.

I have an application that can connect to my device (using the BluetoothLeGatt example code) but now I am stuck on getting the characteristic data, parsing it, and displaying it.

I have tried to take the first value (temperature) data[0], and convert it to a string like in the BluetoothLeGatt example.

In BluetoothLeService.java, I have done the following:

```
public final static String EXTRA_TEMP =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_TEMP";
...

final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data[0]);
                for(byte byteChar : data)
                    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEMP, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
            }
```

And in DeviceControlActivity.java, I added the following at the top:

```
private TextView mTemp;
```

In the BroadcastReceiver function, I added the following for displaying temperature:

```
else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {

        displayTemp(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_TEMP)); }
```

In the OnCreate function, I added the following:

`mTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperature);`

Finally, I added this function at the bottom:

```
private void displayTemp(String data) {
    if (data != null) {
        mTemp.setText(data);
    }
}
```

I am confident my layout file is correctly done, but I cannot see any values displayed where I have my placeholder for the `temperature` id.

Any suggestions on what to do? My goal is to copy the above for all 4 variables once I get this one working.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?